# Artifact on my model's nose

Tags: modeling, mesh, artifacts

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3K7GuHzSiUE&t=311) for making a 3d avatar from scratch, and found that there was an artefact on the nose of my model. The modifiers used are the mirror modifier along the x axis and the subdivision modifier.

0 subdivisions:
[image]
1 subdivisions:
[image]

Can anyone explain why this artifact is occurring and what I can do to remove it?

Comment: Do you have clipping turned on on your mirror modifier? It looks like the vertex just up from the nose tip is "not connected" to the mirrored side.

Comment: Unfortunately, my mirror modifier's clipping is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Catmull-Clark subdivision works well-- meaning, it makes smooth meshes-- under certain circumstances.  One of those circumstances is roughly planar quads.  Here, your quads are most definitely not-planar.  How can we tell?  The biggest clue is that you have two quads that share *three* vertices.  That should never happen; adjoining quads should only ever share two vertices (ideally, for a 3- or 4-pole) or one vertex (for a 5-pole).  You have a pair of strongly concave faces.

We can fix it just by insetting a new face in those two, then scaling that new face down in it's normal Z axis to make it more planar:

[image]

This does come at the cost of creating non-planar 3-poles, which are to be avoided for C-C subdivision, but are not as serious of a problem.

But also, poles can be moved to better locations; the more planar the neighborhood of the pole, the better.  Techniques for moving poles are dealt with elsewhere so I won't cover them in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem a few months back, my solution to this was checking for duplicate vertex, check if a face on the inside of the mesh is preventing the merge, and recalculate normals, that or your vertex isnt aligned to 0 properly.

most of the time i fixed it by recalculating normals with Shift N
hope it helps